# Importing table rates "Invalid Region/State" [Magento]

Tags: magento-1.9, php, shipping-methods

in configuration system in payment method, i want to add shipment cost for a product based on destination, and then i added my country ID , Region/state ,... etc
[image]

when i import this file and click on save config i have this error

[image]

Comment: Did you ever faced following issue, Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps metrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento doesn't ship with alot of regions for many countrys. You need to manually add them to your database prior to setting up matrix table shipping rates. See how to add them here. Switch to the webshop rates plugin, it has manymore features than the standard and its free.
http://webshopapps.com/blog/2011/04/adding-new-regionsstates-to-your-magento-installation-2/

Comment: Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps metrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate.